# Setting uniform values into the fragment shader (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl

I'm studying OpenGL with GLUT and GLEW library.
But I have a question about setting uniform values into the program's fragment shader.

Here's a part of the fragment shader code.

```
#version 110 
uniform vec4 cameraPosition;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;

varying vec4 fragColor;
varying vec4 fragNormal;
varying vec4 fragPosition;

void main() {
    vec4 L = lightPosition - fragPosition;
    vec4 V = cameraPosition - fragPosition;
```

What I want to do is set 'cameraPosition' and 'lightPosition' uniform variables.
Also, in the main program, I put some code to get these variables ID and pass some values into the variables like below.

```
GLuint cameraPositionID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "cameraPosition");
GLuint lightPositionID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "lightPosition");
GLfloat camPos[4] = { 1, 1, -3, 1 };
GLfloat lightPos[4] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
glUniform4fv(cameraPositionID, 4, &cameraPos[0]);
glUniform4fv(lightPositionID, 4, &lightPos[0]);
```

So, I try to pass camPos into cameraPosition, and lightPos into lightPosition.
is it correct or incorrect? If you think incorrect, Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` parameter of `glUniform4fv` denotes how many elements of an uniform array you are going to set - in this case, how many `vec4`s. You don't have an array, so `count` must be one. According to the spec, your command should result in a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, and not in setting any uniform values. (Apart from that, using count 4 would also read 16 floats from the memory, while your array is only 4 floats big).

It is also unclear if you did a `glUspeProgram(programID)` before you try to set these uniforms. As uniforms are per-program state, the `glUniform*()` commands apply only to the currently bound program.

Comment: okay, It's now clear after I put 1 into the count, instead of 4. Much thanks :) :D:D